# How to get Notified before SMS is Sent in android

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible that i can get Notification when Handset sends SMS and get the receiver's Number before the SMS is sent. I used `BroadcasrReceiver` to get notification of Incoming Message.But in same way i am not able to track outgoing SMS message by using `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"`
Please Help....Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have searched a lot regarding the Outgoing Message notification.But i think its not possible thru Third Party application.
Is it possible thru Android SDK by making code in c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think such is possible, once the phone has granted the application the permission to send SMS, there is little or nothing you can do about it as the user.